# Edit dynamically pseudo-elements with angular 2

Tags: css, angular, pseudo-element

I'm trying to edit dynamically that kind of css property in an angular 2 project, but with no success :(

```
 progress::-moz-progress-bar {
            background: #278ce2;
        }
```

I want to add n progressbars on the same page. The color of the background is chosen by the user and is switched dynamically. The idea was to add a css property to each bar created like this :

```
 classname::-moz-progress-bar {
        background: color;
    }
 classname::-webkit-progress-value {
        background: color;
    }
 classname[aria-valuenow]:before {
        background: color;
    }
```

As I want the possibility to create as much bars as the user wants, I can't name the classes before.

Does anybody have an idea on how to do that ? If you need more details, just ask me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't find out how to edit those pseudo-elements. But I managed to do what I want by recreating progress bars with div. Here's the code if it can help somebody :

In HTML (with Angular 2)

```
<div class="probar">
  <div class="inside-probar" [ngStyle]="{background:color, width: ((value * 100)/max) + '%'}">
    {{value}}/{{max}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In CSS

```
.probar{
  height: 20px;
  width: 140px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 3px;
}

.inside-probar{
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  color: black;
}
```